# Visual Studio 2013 The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ftp

FTP deployment has stopped working on Visual Studio 2013 and I get the error:

> The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a recent installation of Xamarin. Once I uninstalled all the components normal service was resumed.

Had to share this one...

Comment: Just uninstalled Xamarin, but the issue isn't fixed for me.

Comment: Following this article for uninstalling Xamarin solved it. Reboot required.
https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699832-how-do-i-perform-a-thorough-uninstall-for-xamarin-for-visual-studio-